# a simpler proof for an inequality in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am trying to show that for any two real $X,Y$ iid there holds that

$$ P(|X - Y| \le 2) \leq 3P(|X - Y| \le 1) $$

I am getting nowhere with this and so I did some digging and found the following reference that proves a more general result:

http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/123.pdf

However the special case that I am trying to show is just an exercise in a book that I am working through, so I suspect there must be a simpler proof for it. Also I would like to do it from first principles if possible rather then quoting a bigger result and say it's a special case.

Comment: Your exercise is the smallest case of Lemma 2.1 and Corollary 2.2; you can just mimic those proofs.

Comment: Yes, true! But do you think there is an even simpler argument ?

Comment: Perhaps there is a simpler argument, building on the ideas of the section containing this problem, and building on the preceding problems.  Not having this information it is very difficult for me to provide any guidance.